# Subtraction of CHARINDEX in SUBSTRING is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, charindex

I have a value that I need to break down in column Name: `AB: ABC-ABCDE` I need the middle part which is `ABC`. I am using SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX to accomplish this but I am getting an error:

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 393
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

This happens when I subtract CHARINDEX to get the last value in SUBSTRING.
Code:

```
SELECT PRODUCT = (SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(' ',Name)+1,CHARINDEX('-',Name)-(CHARINDEX(' ',Name)+1)))
FROM A
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: There is another value in the table like: `'ABC-ABC: ABCDEFG-ABCDEF GH'`. This gives negative value, hence why the error. Result should be `ABCDEFG`

Comment: The expression resulted in an out of scope value and hence the error. Evaluate the expressions individually to find if the parameter values being evaluated are correct for a string.

Comment: @Dheerendra I did evaluate them separately and I am getting numbers for both values so it should be able to subtract

Comment: what if the subtraction results in a negative value? Evaluate the subtraction as well and check

Comment: I did evaluate and no it does not result in the negative value because I have switched the greater length towards the beginning. How else I can achieve this, if not subtraction?

Comment: I run into this occasionally and it's *always* an edge case resulting in a negative length. Really frustrating to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to "force" the NULL with a `NullIf()`

**Example**

```
... NullIf(CHARINDEX(' ',Name),0) + 1 ...

... NullIf(CHARINDEX('-',Name),0) ...
```

**

> **EDIT- Requested Update**

**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Name varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
( 'AB: ABC-ABCDE')
,('ABC-ABC: ABCDEFG-ABCDEF GH')

Select A.*
      ,ltrim(rtrim(left(substring(Name,charindex(':',Name+':')+1,len(Name))
           ,charindex('-',substring(Name,charindex(':',Name+':')+1,len(Name))+'-') -1
           )))
 From  @YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
Name                          (No column name)
AB: ABC-ABCDE                 ABC
ABC-ABC: ABCDEFG-ABCDEF GH    ABCDEFG
```

Comment: @Stephanie Given the update, what portion of the string are you looking for?

Comment: After the semicolon and before the dash that comes after semicolon. If the value is 'ABC-ABC: ABCDEFG-ABCDEF GH' then I want ' ABCDEFG'

Comment: @Stephanie I'm pleased you were able to get to a solution.   Always happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You have no space.  I find that the simplest way is to just add one:

```
SELECT PRODUCT = (SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name + ' ') + 1, CHARINDEX('-', Name + '-') - (CHARINDEX(' ', Name + ' ') + 1)))
FROM A
```

I'm not 100% sure this does what you want, but it will fix the error you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

You might go another route:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('AB: ABC-ABCDE')
                         ,('CD: blah-blub')
                         ,('Wrong Value here')
                         ,('MissingEnd: isCorrect');
```

--The query will pick the second element out of an XML.

```
SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPlACE(REPLACE(m.SomeValue,'-',' '),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @mockup m;
```

The trick is: Use some replacements to transform your *AB: ABC-ABCDE* into an XML like

```
<x>AB:</x>
<x>ABC</x>
<x>ABCDE</x>
```

From this XML we can easily pick the second element.

One positive side effect: This approach is much more tolerant with bad values...

### UPDATE

Your bad values... The new trick is to cut away everything up to the double-dot using `STUFF()`:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('AB: ABC-ABCDE')
                         ,('CD: blah-blub')
                         ,('Wrong Value here')
                         ,('MissingEnd: isCorrect')
                         ,('ABC-ABC: ABCDEFG-ABCDEF GH');

SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPlACE(REPLACE(STUFF(m.SomeValue,1,CHARINDEX(':',m.SomeValue),''),'-',' '),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @mockup m;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue cannot be reproduced.

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(31) = 'AB: ABC-ABCDE';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Name, CHARINDEX(' ',@Name)+1,CHARINDEX('-',@Name)-(CHARINDEX(' ',@Name)+1))
```

Results in `ABC`.

Probably you have some data in your table that doesn't fit the format you claim it has.

Comment: You are right, i probably have another value which gives a negative value to subtract from. Is there anything else I can use to achieve this? Not sure how I can manage negatives.

Comment: What you should do depends on what form the non-conforming data takes, and what result you want to get when you encounter it.   You would need to add that to your question before I could offer any specific suggestions.  If you want NULL, you can use John's answer, if you want everything before the hyphen you can use Gordon's answer.

Comment: I really don't understand it myself either. I did evaluate the data closely. I did the subtraction separately to see if there are any negative values but I don't see anything like. It works when i filter on individual row but when I do it for the whole table, it is not working. Thank you for your help, i'll update you if i find something

Comment: I found the issue, there is a dash in first part of the value for example: 'ABC-ABC: ABCDEFG-ABCDEF GH'

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are spaces where you don't expect them to be.  
So get the substring from `":"` to `"-"` and trim it:

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(':',Name)+1,CHARINDEX('-',Name)-(CHARINDEX(':',Name)+1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TEXT AS VARCHAR(20)
    SET @TEXT='E1014654-1'
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@TEXT, CHARINDEX('E', @TEXT)+1, CHARINDEX('-',@TEXT)) as 'STR', 
            CAST(CHARINDEX('E', @Text)+1 AS INT) as 'val1', CAST(CHARINDEX('-', @TEXT) AS INT) as 'val2',  
            (CAST(CHARINDEX('-',@TEXT) AS INT) - CAST(CHARINDEX('E',@TEXT)+1 AS INT)) as 'SUBTR', LEN(@TEXT) as 'LEN'
END
```

The values in val1 and val2 when I actually subtract them, they give me a numeric value that is consistent with the operation.

If you run the same thing without the cast, it does not result in the same value:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TEXT2 AS VARCHAR(20)
    SET @TEXT2='E1014654-1'
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@TEXT2, CHARINDEX('E', @TEXT2)+1, CHARINDEX('-',@TEXT2)) as 'STR', 
            CHARINDEX('E', @TEXT2)+1  as 'val1', CHARINDEX('-', @TEXT2) as 'val2',  
            CHARINDEX('-',@TEXT2)  - CHARINDEX('E',@TEXT2)+1 as 'SUBTR', LEN(@TEXT2) as 'LEN'
END
```

It's involved, but it works. I rather see SQL have an `INSTR` or `GetStr` function that will return a string that matches or `NULL` if it doesn't exist.